# SDL_FillRect changing values

Tags: c++, sdl

Im trying to cover small rectangles within an `SDL_Surface *` by using `SDL_FillRect()` with the following code:

```
        int display(SDL_Surface * screen, Uint16 tile_size){
            if (!screen)
                return 1;
            std::cout << x << " " << y << std::endl;
            SDL_Rect pos = {(Sint16) (x * tile_size), (Sint16) ((y - 2) * tile_size), tile_size, tile_size};
            std::cout << pos.x << " " << pos.y << std::endl;
            for(uint8_t Y = 0; Y < 4; Y++){
                pos.x = x * tile_size;
                for(uint8_t X = 0; X < 4; X++){
//                    bit mask check to see which bits should be displayed. 
//                    not relevant to question
//                    if (shape[orientation][Y] & (1U << (3 - X))){
                        std::cout << pos.x << " " << pos.y << " -> ";
                        SDL_FillRect(screen, &pos, color);
                        std::cout << pos.x << " " << pos.y << std::endl;
//                    }
                    pos.x += tile_size;
                }
                pos.y += tile_size;
            }
            std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }
```

x ranges from 0 to 9, y ranges from 0 to 21, tile_size is small (25 right now).

When this code is run, the output is the following:

```
3 0                             // x y
75 -50                          // x*tile_size y*tile_size
75 -50 -> 75 0                  // what in the world?
100 0 -> 100 0
125 0 -> 125 0
150 0 -> 150 0
75 25 -> 75 25
100 25 -> 100 25
125 25 -> 125 25
150 25 -> 150 25
75 50 -> 75 50
100 50 -> 100 50
125 50 -> 125 50
150 50 -> 150 50
75 75 -> 75 75
100 75 -> 100 75
125 75 -> 125 75
150 75 -> 150 75
```

The third line (first displayed rectangle) is somehow moved from being at -50 to 0. It is throwing off my display calculations. What is wrong? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: _Have you tried looking at the return value for SDL_FillRect? If it's -1 there might be some error internally that is causing the position to change._ ignore that, look at my answer

Comment: All the `SDL_FillRect` return values are 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw this when I was looking through the documentation: "If there is a clip rectangle set on the destination (set via `SDL_SetClipRect`) then this function will clip based on the intersection of the clip rectangle and the `dstrect` rectangle and the `dstrect` rectangle will be modified to represent the area actually filled."

This indicates that there is a clip rectangle causing the issue.

That clip rectangle is a property contained in your `SDL_Surface`, and probably starts at (0,0). That would make any negative numbers become 0 after the `SDL_FillRect()` call is made.

You could fix this by passing a reference to a copy of the `dstrect`.

Source: http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlfillrect.html